# ASP.NET C# Nested controlls access

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got something like that

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="litControlTitle" runat="server" />
      <label id="test" runat="server">dw</label>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Can someone tell me, how should I change label text, using C# code?
Main problem for me is- how to get access to the nested control (label, literal) from c# code?

EDITED:

```
<SelectedItemTemplate>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="NumberEdit" runat="server"
                        Value='<%# Bind("numbers") %>' />

                    <label for="NameEdit">Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NameEdit" Width="160px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="NameEdit_TextChanged"
                        Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'  />
                    <br />

                                    <label for="ShortcutEdit">Shortcut:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ShortcutEdit" Width="80px" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Bind("Shortcut") %>' />
                    <br />
```

and I would like to generate automatically Shortcut text when user will change Name (Shortcut = 2 first letters from NameEdit)? Can you explain me, how should I do it? –

Answer (score 2):

You would want to have an [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event handler to get access to the controls for that particular item in your listview. The example on the page I linked should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you need a data source binded with this `ListView` control, for example `SqlDataSource`, or any other allowed type you need:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [id] FROM [Articles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
        // rest of the code
    </asp:ListView>
```

Second thing is that controls from `LayoutTemplate` template will be rendered only if there is any data to show. So if you have datasource, but it is empty, this tamplate will not be applied. But you can use `EmptyDataTemplate` to display info when there is nothing from the datasource to display.

And then, when you already have datasource defined and binded to your `ListView` and there is data that will be displayed, the `LayoutTemplate` will be rendered. And then you can use `FindControl` method of the `ListView`. As for example of getting this literal:

```
Literal l = (Literal)lv.FindControl("litControlTitle");
```

It's returning null for you because you have no data to display, so controls are not rendered at all.

Comment: Well...it doesn't work. I always have respons = "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code".

Comment: @mkdir I updated my answer to point out what's missing in your code.

Comment: I don't unterstand. I've got normal listview with data binding from database. And when my control (this one for which I need access from c#) is inside <layouttemplate> then everything is ok, in any other case, when I add it for example inside <selecteditemtemplate> then it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I'll write for what I need it. I've got something like [code]<pre><code><SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NameEdit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="NameEdit_TextChanged"
                        Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'  />
                  
<asp:TextBox ID="ShortcutEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Shortcut") %>'  />
            
</SelectedItemTemplate></code></pre> and I would like to generate automatically Shortcut text when user will change Name (Shortcut = 2 first letters from NameEdit)? Can you explain me, how should I do it?

Comment: @mkdir Please update your question with this code and the code you tried yo achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Label)ListView1.FindControl("test")).Text = "Hello!";
```

Comment: You might want to explain your code rather than just dumping it.

Comment: I've got "NullReferenceException".